# Make Youtube live streaming available to another country after end streaming

Tags: streaming, youtube, live

I have an youtube channel that makes a lot of live streams.
But i have different countries watching at the same hour in its own time zone.

I have a live streaming on Brazil starting 6PM and finishing 9/9:30 PM (GMT -2). But i can't finish my live stream because people on USA start to watch the live stream at 6PM (GMT -5) from the start of live stream. I need to stream black until they finish to watch at their 9/9:30PM (GMT -5).

If i finish the stream, they can't watch. There is somo way to do not have this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

YouTube can record the live stream so that it can be played back any time afterwards.

You need to select archiving of the live stream, and then publish that archive.

I'm pretty certain the default is to archive the live stream, so you should check it in your settings, in case you have disabled it for some reason.